# How can I print colors when printing a page in bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, printing, colors

I'm trying to print a page with colors on my asp.net site.  But all the colors just come out white.  However my Highcharts colors and images come out in color.  I'm using Bootstrap 3, not sure if that is affecting anything, and I've also check the box to print background colors. Does anyone know why my colors aren't printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution shortly after posting the question.  The following line in bootstrap.css needs to be changed.

```
@media print{*{text-shadow:none !important;color:#000 !important;background:transparent !important;box-shadow:none !important;}
```

For my purposes I removed the `color:` and `background:` properties.

Comment: a better solution would be to override this somehow. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Try checking that your browser has background colors turned on in the print settings

Answer (score 6):

You can override Bootstrap's settings back to "inherit" with something like this in your CSS (remember to include your CSS *after* Bootstrap):

```
@media print {
    * {
        color: inherit !important;
        background: inherit !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print
{
    /* color:#000!important; */    
    text-shadow:none!important;
    /*  background:transparent!important; */
    box-shadow:none!important
 }
```

You can remove (or comment out) color & background style `@media print` from your bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css whichever you have referenced in your site (master page)...

It worked for me !! It will print the webpage with its color format.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jonathan solution is on the right way, although is not working for me.

As @pixelearth said in comments, the best solution would be probably to override the `@media print` that comes from Bootstrap CSS. But you cannot use the `inherit` option in this case.

In my case, overriding `@media print` works fine if I set the two properties `color` and `background` as they are set in the page CSS.

If you want to override Bootstrap's `@media print` CSS, you have to include a new CSS file **after** Bootstrap's CSS (minified or not).

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/printable-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is the content of my `printable-page.css` CSS file:

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        color: #b01717 !important;
        background: transparent !important;
    }
}
```

As I said, the two valus `color: #b01717` and `background: transparent` come from the main CSS of the site (from `body` or `page` section).

Maybe this can be a limited solution for someone, but in my case the "printable" page has a very simple style and I can also avoid to edit the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Modify following in bootstrap.css file

```
@media print {
*, *:before, *:after {
background:transparent !important;
/*color:#000 !important;*/
-webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
box-shadow:none !important;
text-shadow:none !important
}
```

Add following code in your css file

```
@media print {
    * :not(.printDefaultcolor *) {
        color: #000 !important;
    }
}
```

Use in your html as

```
<div class="printDefaultcolor">
your html code
<span style="font-weight: bold;">bold </span>  <span class="text-success">color </span>  
</div>
```